# How to calculate the number of days between stages in this df Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign ID':[48464,48464,48464,48464,26380,26380,22676,39529,39529,46029,46029,46029,17030,46724,46724,39379,39379,39379],
'Campaign stage':["Lost","Developing","Discussing","Starting","Discussing", "Starting","Developing",    "Discussing","Starting","Developing",   "Discussing","Starting","Developing",   "Developing","Discussing","Lost",   "Developing","Discussing"],
'Stage Number':[-1, 3,  2,  1,  2,  1,  3,  2,  1,  3,  2,  1,  3,  3,  2,  -1, 3,  2],
'Campaign Date':["2/8/2019","1/9/2019","1/3/2019","3/3/2018","2/14/2019","12/5/2018","7/25/2018","6/8/2018","3/4/2018","12/8/2018","9/9/2018","5/31/2018","6/7/2018","3/27/2018","1/6/2018","2/15/2019","12/15/2018","9/4/2018"]})

pvt = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Campaign stage'],index=['Campaign ID','Campaign stage','Stage Number','Campaign Date'],aggfunc='count')
pvt.sort_values(['Campaign ID','Campaign Date'],ascending=[True,False])
```

Hi guys, I have the above dataframe and I'd like to calculate the number of days between campaign stage "starting" and "discussing" for each campaign and then calculate the average.

Because of the data quality, the campaign stages are not consistent. So, for campaigns don't have the two stages "starting" and "discussing", I want to set as 0.

I created a pivot table view of the data and sorted the campaign date descending order...But I don't know how to do next.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposal, starting from your df:

```
df['Campaign Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Campaign Date'])
df = df[df['Campaign stage'].isin(['Starting', 'Discussing'])]

pvt = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Campaign stage'],index=['Campaign ID','Campaign stage','Stage Number','Campaign Date'],aggfunc='count')
pvt = pvt.sort_values(['Campaign ID','Campaign Date'],ascending=True).reset_index(level=3)

pvt.groupby(level=0).diff().sum(level=0)
```

The output would be:

```
Campaign ID - Campaign Date
26380   71 days
39379   0 days
39529   96 days
46029   101 days
46724   0 days
48464   306 days
```

If what you are looking for is the total mean:

```
pvt.groupby(level=0).diff().sum(level=0).mean()
```

Which is:

```
95 days 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Campaign Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Campaign Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
compare= {}
for ids,gp in df.groupby('Campaign ID'):
    try:
        compare[ids]= gp.loc[gp['Campaign stage']=='Discussing']['Campaign Date'].iloc[0] - gp.loc[gp['Campaign stage']=='Starting']['Campaign Date'].iloc[0]
    except:
        compare[ids] =0

df['new_col'] = df['Campaign ID'].apply(lambda x:compare[x])
```

Comment: Welcome @Jancos

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure in which form you would like your end result to be, the below sample assumes you want it in a new dataframe.

We can go multiple route, though, I chose to create a function below and decompose each step for clarity.

- Step 1: update your date data type to [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for comparison
- Step 2: call out function    Step 2.1: define empty list to store our cids values and days between `starting` and `discussing`

  - Step 2.2:
    Get all unique `cid` and iterate through each one
  - Step 2.3: Check if the `cid` has both staging we are interested with

    - Step 2.3.1: if not assign 0 to this `cid`
    - Step 2.3.2: else calculate the difference between `discussing` and `starting`
  - Step 2.4: create our new dataframe and return it
  - Step 2.5: Using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) create and calculate our average day index

**Code**

```
# First we need to modify your data type to compare the dates
df['Campaign Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Campaign Date'])

df_days = getDays(df)

# We create a new index called 'Average' that will assign values to the days column
df_days.loc['Average','days'] = df_days.days.mean()

def getDays(df):
    days = list()
    cids = list()

    for cid in df['Campaign ID'].unique():
        stages = df[(df['Campaign ID'] == cid) & 
                    (df['Campaign stage'].str.lower().isin(['discussing', 'starting']))]['Campaign stage'].unique()

        if len(stages) < 2:
            d = 0
            c = cid

            days.append(d)
            cids.append(c)

        else:
            starting = df[(df['Campaign ID'] == cid) & (df['Campaign stage'].str.lower() == 'starting')]['Campaign Date'].dt.date.values
            discussing = df[(df['Campaign ID'] == cid) & (df['Campaign stage'].str.lower() == 'discussing')]['Campaign Date'].dt.date.values

            d = (discussing - starting)[0].days

            c = cid

            days.append(d)
            cids.append(c)


    dff = pd.DataFrame({
        'cids': cids,
        'days': days
    })          

    return dff
```

**Out**

```
        cids    days
0       48464.0 306.00
1       26380.0 71.00
2       22676.0 0.00
3       39529.0 96.00
4       46029.0 101.00
5       17030.0 0.00
6       46724.0 0.00
7       39379.0 0.00
Average NaN   71.75
```

Comment: Thanks for your coding. That's helpful!